# Hola compañeros estoy intentando acceder a las coordendas de google map

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

Estoy intentando obtener las coordenadas (latitud, longitud) del `Json` que me devuelve **Google Map**.

El `Json` es el siguiente:

```
{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Calle Jorge Isaac","short_name":"Calle Jorge Isaac","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Surquillo","short_name":"Surquillo","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Provincia de Lima","short_name":"Provincia de Lima","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Municipalidad Metropolitana de Lima","short_name":"Municipalidad Metropolitana de Lima","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Perú","short_name":"PE","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"15036","short_name":"15036","types":["postal_code"]}],"adr_address":"<span class=\"street-address\">Calle Jorge Isaac</span>, <span class=\"locality\">Surquillo</span> <span class=\"postal-code\">15036</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">Perú</span>","formatted_address":"Calle Jorge Isaac, Surquillo 15036, Perú","geometry":{"location":{"lat":-12.1115587,"lng":-77.01023709999998},"viewport":{"south":-12.1129076802915,"west":-77.01158608029152,"north":-12.1102097197085,"east":-77.0088881197085}},"icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png","id":"1b6fd0fe15d2aa69310978593005b8f889fe20d8","name":"Calle Jorge Isaac","place_id":"ChIJvTEC_-HHBZERk1kVH3tiJRE","reference":"CmRbAAAAmkwolyd9ostqftkab2gGg0jHcqw5E10icueLEk5MWMWTI0VPO3FwnD66kdRHCy6EO4UL7z-CsGsUXsQDgY-o1RME4H3LNBdxi_mxXCZ0Fh3uVIfHYSsFyP96EExb49wMEhCh4mcujv-KM8udTnFOrMN-GhSIrgqHphvXktf9iOaMqEPr-vPHxA","scope":"GOOGLE","types":["route"],"url":"https://maps.google.com/?q=Calle+Jorge+Isaac,+Surquillo+15036,+Per%C3%BA&ftid=0x9105c7e1ff0231bd:0x1125627b1f155993","utc_offset":-300,"vicinity":"Surquillo","html_attributions":[]}
```

[image: Imagen de json donde esta las Coordendas]

Comment: Que código tenes hasta ahora?, que has probado?

Comment: Buenas, que problema estas teniendo exactamente?
Si lo que necesitas es obtener los datos del JSON de lat y lng podrías intentar:
`tuObjeto.geometry.localtion.lat //te daría el lat
tuObjeto.geometry.localtion.lng //te daría el lng`

Comment: Tengo este codigo:    var coordenadas = autocomplete.getPlace();
  
 var CoordenadasJson = JSON.stringify(coordenadas) ;


  for (var y = 0; i < CoordenadasJson.geometry.length; i++) {
    
    var LongLati = CoordenadasJson.geometry[y];
    if (componentForm[LongLati]) {
      var val = CoordenadasJson.geometry[y][componentForm[LongLati]];
      alert(val)
      //document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y adicionar el código para poder leerlo mejor?

Comment: var CoordenadasJson = JSON.stringify(coordenadas) ;

//tuObjeto.geometry.localtion.lat //te daría el lat tuObjeto.geometry.localtion.lng

  alert(CoordenadasJson.geometry.location.lat) pero la consola del navegador me da el siguiente error: TypeError: CoordenadasJson.geometry is undefined

Comment: Si haces un console.log de cordenadas, que tiene adentro?

Comment: JSON:stringify(coordenadas) devuelve en consola:    el JSON que esta en la pregunta

Comment: No puedes hacer el  JSON.stringify esto lo convierte en STRING, debes utilizar JSON.parse(coordenadas) para poder usarlo como un objeto.

Comment: al hacer JSON.parse(coordenadas) la consola me arroja el siguiente error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data[Saber más]

Comment: Si ya tienes coordenadas como un objeto no tienes que hacerle nada. Solo usa `coordenadas.geometry.location.lat` `coordenadas.geometry.location.lng`

Comment: Listo amigos lo resolvi de la siguiente Manera:  placeJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(place))

  alert( placeJson.geometry.location.lat );

Comment: Excelente, que bueno que funciono. JSON.parse y JSON.stringify son funciones contrarias, si estas teniendo que hacerlo así, me parece extraño ya que deberías poder usar `place.geometry.location.lat` pero mientras te funcione, todo bien :)

Comment: si amigo es curioso, pero el Json que me devuelve Google-maps, Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas.